# Ojdbc7.jar is in CLASSPATH, but java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oci8, java.lang.class

I've seen a lot of similarly questions here, but I can't find my case.

I wrote a demo program to check JDBC. Here is the beginning of it:

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
import java.io.*;

class JdbcCheckup {
    public static void main(String args[])
    throws SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        OracleConnection conn = null;
        conn = (OracleConnection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:oci8:usr/pass@ldap:host");
        // ...
```

Then I run the following and got `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
$ /usr/java71_64/bin/javac -cp /oracle/client/o12r1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc7.jar demo.java
$ /usr/java71_64/bin/jar -cvfm demo.jar MANIFEST.MF JdbcCheckup.class
added manifest
adding: JdbcCheckup.class(in = 2345) (out = 1356)(deflated 42%)
$ /usr/java71_64/bin/java -cp /oracle/client/o12r1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc7.jar:/oracle/client/o12r1/jlib/orai18n.jar -Djava.library.path=$ORACLE_HOME/lib -jar demo.jar
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:199)
        at JdbcCheckup.main(demo.java:27)
```

In the `ojdbc7.jar` I can see `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` class:

```
$ /usr/java71_64/bin/jar -tf /oracle/client/o12r1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc7.jar | grep Driver
META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver
oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.class
oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver$1.class
oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver.class
oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriverExtension.class
oracle/jdbc/driver/T2CDriverExtension.class
oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CDriverExtension.class
```

So please explain what do I do wrong?

Comment: are you sure you dont want `oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver.class`?

Comment: if you have a classpath defined in MANIFEST.MF `-cp` will not be evaluated. How Looks your classpath in the manifest?

Comment: @Jens , my MANIFEST.MF just defines main-class: `Main-Class: JdbcCheckup`

Comment: remove the manifest and try again

Comment: Without a manifest I got the error: `no main manifest attribute in demo.jar`(

Comment: If you execute with `-jar`, then the classpath **must** be defined in the manifest. Please post your current manifest; the `-cp` classpath is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot!

As recommended in comments, I added `Class-Path` in my manifest file.

```
$ cat MANIFEST.MF
Main-Class: JdbcCheckup
Class-Path: /oracle/client/o12r1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc7.jar /oracle/client/o12r1/jlib/orai18n.jar

$ /usr/java71_64/bin/javac -cp /oracle/client/o12r1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc7.jar demo.java
$ /usr/java71_64/bin/jar -cvfm demo.jar MANIFEST.MF JdbcCheckup.class
added manifest
adding: JdbcCheckup.class(in = 2345) (out = 1356)(deflated 42%)
$ /usr/java71_64/bin/java -Djava.library.path=$ORACLE_HOME/lib -jar demo.jar
```